# An array that outputs number 1-5 in random, 1-5 must be output only 2 times without repeating

Tags: java, arrays, random

The code does output 1 - 5 but is there a way to make each number print only twice. (from 1-5 only)
[Sample Output,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5fEP.png)

It does change and is random but outputs more than twice

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
int num;    

int[] random = new int[5]; //this code generates numbers 1–5 

int[] array = new int[11]; //array size

for(int x = 0; x < random.length; x++)

random[x] = x; //store the index as a value

for(int x = 0; x < random.length; x++) {

num = (int)(Math.random()*5);

while(random[num] == -1)

num = (int)(Math.random()*5); 

if(random[num] != -1)

array[x] = random[num]; 

random[num] = -1; 

}

for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)

array[x] = array[x] + 1;

for(int x = 1; x < array.length; x++)


System.out.println("A["+x+"]: "+ array[x]);

}

}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. In its current form, it's pretty hard to read, because of the lack of indentation and excessive newlines.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of the random array? It just complicates things. Instead, generate a random number, and check if it is already used twice. If yes, generate another one, if no put it into the array. Repeat until the array is full. Another approach would be to initialize the array with 2 copies of the numbers 1-5 and to do a random permutation.

Comment: since you can enumerate all the numbers in the result, I suggest you follow Henry's second suggestion - put the numbers 1-5 into an array twice each, then shuffle the array

Comment: @Henry I tried your suggestion it was definitely easier, but the problem given was very specific and had guidelines that I had to follow which that the array generated must be based on the array index and the positioning of the index and to check whether or not the array index is occupied, if so output it to the position. (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable that records the random records then inside the method or function use if else statement to check the random recorded value to the current value then set up again a variable that provides the limitation to your code.

Comment: Just like a counter right? I was trying to use a counter but since there are lots of loops I was having a problem as to where to place it and the value of the counter is not consistent.

Comment: try creating new array then every time the random appears it will check if tha random number is already alocated,if yes then use recursion to call itself.If no, display the number then add the random number to the new array for your reference